# declarations.d.ts in Angular 7

Tags: angular7, typescript-typings

A few days back I switched to Angular 7 and not able to locate declarations.d.ts.

In Angular 2 and 4, I used declarations.d.ts to define the typing for JQUERY and others -

```
interface JQuery {
  datepicker(options: any): JQuery;
  modal(options: any): JQuery;
}
```

Where to define unknown element interface in Angular 7 ?

Note: I used Angular CLI to generate the project.

Answer (score -1):

Use `typings.d.ts` in `/src` folder.

More info here: [TypeScript Configuration](https://angular.io/guide/typescript-configuration)

**UPDATE**

Better way of achieving your goal is to use [jQuery's typings](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/jquery).
Be sure to add:

```
"typeRoots": [
  "node_modules/@types"
],
```

to your `tsconfig.json` so typescript knows where to search for types.
Most famous libraries will have their typings package out there, so first try to get it from npm, if not found than you always can define them in `typings.d.ts`

Comment: There is no such file typings.d.ts in angular 7.

Comment: @Kanchan Have you tried adding it and defining needed interface? And also if you need types for jquery you can always use `npm install --save @types/jquery`.